# Using a subquery in place of a SELECT fieldname ...or how to achieve the same result?

Tags: mysql, insert, subquery

My goal is to get a collection of ID's from `Table 1` based on a query, a collection of ID's from `Table 2` based on a query, and insert a new record into `Table 3` for each permutation.

Basically, this:

```
INSERT INTO `TABLE3` (Field1,Field2,Field3)
SELECT null,`UID`, (SELECT `UID` FROM `TABLE2` WHERE `IsDefault` = 1)
FROM `TABLE1`
WHERE `Group` LIKE 'V';
```

So if the subquery:

```
(SELECT `UID` FROM `TABLE2` WHERE `IsDefault` = 1)
```

returns a list of IDs:

```
1, 2, 3
```

And the main select query:

```
SELECT null,`UID`, $i
FROM `TABLE1`
WHERE `Group` LIKE 'V';
```

returns another list of IDs:

```
200, 300, 400
```

Then `TABLE3` after the query runs should be:

```
1 - 200
1 - 300
1 - 400
2 - 200
2 - 300
2 - 400
3 - 200
3 - 300
3 - 400
```

When I tried the above query, I get:

```
#2014 - Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now
```

So I'm not sure what the proper syntax is to do an INSERT...SELECT  where one of the "hard values" should be treated as a "foreach" variable from the subquery results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is called a Cartesian product and uses `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT NULL, t1.UID, t2.UID
FROM table1 t1
CROSS JOIN table2 t2
WHERE T1.`Groups` LIKE 'V'
    AND t2. `IsDefault` = 1;
```

This mixes each rows from table1 with each rows from table2.  (see [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a3d7/1/0))

Comment: Fun fact: While logically they are **not** the same, CROSS JOIN is an alias to JOIN in MySQL http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5a3d7/2

Comment: While the ON clause is optional with MySQL (unlike standard SQL), I think it is better to explicitly write CROSS JOIN when a Cartesian product is needed. A JOIN alone may look like the ON clause has been forgotten or removed by mistake.